# Get all fields in the Joi schema that are optjonal

Tags: hapi.js

How do I get an array or list of field names that were set to optional in Joi object?

For example:

```
export const schema = Joi.object<SomeType>({
  field1: Joi.string().required(),
  field2: Joi.string().guid(),
  field3: Joi.string().allow('').optional(),
  field4: Joi.string().allow('').optional(),
});
```

I should be able to retrieved field3, field4.

Hapi Joi https://www.npmjs.com/package/@hapi/joi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`describe`](https://github.com/sideway/joi/blob/master/API.md#anydescribe) to do so:

> Returns an object that represents the internal configuration of the
> schema. Useful for debugging and exposing a schema's configuration to
> other systems, like valid values in a user interface.

And here we go:

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(queueSchemaBase.describe().keys)) {
  if (value.flags?.presence === 'optional') {
    console.log(`${key} is optional`);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
field3 is optional
field4 is optional
```